# Having trouble installing animation nodes addon

Tags: add-on, animation-nodes

Im trying to install the animation nodes add-on to blender but I cant see the zip file when I click *install*. I know i'm in the right location, the file just doesn't show up.
This is probably a total rookie mistake but I am a total rookie.
Any ideas?

Comment: Back to basics ...
What OS are you using? In Windows, are your file extensions turned off? Outside of Blender (such as file explorer) - can you see the zip file you are looking for?

Comment: Im using macOS and I can see it in finder

Comment: I made the mistake of downloading the Github repo as a zip file. That doesn't work. You need to get it from here (if you made the same mistake as me) https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases